# Story with joke-telling time traveller

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, super-hero

I can't remember where I read this prose story, but in it there are superheroes. One of the superheroes can travel backward in time, but experiences all of the time that he travels through (so traveling 1 day back would cause him to experience 1 day of time in limbo).

The hero ages faster because of all this time spent in limbo, but he also gets bored, and tells jokes to himself to pass the time.

He wasn't the main character in the story, but was a viewpoint character at times. He was a masked superhero, and I think I read the story online.

The main character was a different superhero who did not dress in a costume (and did not have a secret identity). He has a normal name (like Bob or Joe), and his superhero name was something like "Amazing Bob" or something like that. I believe he was considered powerful in the story world, and in a portion of the story someone clones him a lot (4 times?) and makes the clones try to kill him.

The story was named after the main character, and his superpowers were pretty much similar to Superman's powers (flight, speed, strength, laser vision, etc.) Additionally, the main character had money problems and had to keep a day job because people never paid him for his superhero work. He is friends with the time traveling superhero and sometimes asks for the time traveller's help in order to save the day because the time traveller has a power (time travel) that he doesn't have.

To me the main character was less exciting than the time travelling masked hero who told jokes, so I am focusing on him. However the story was really about the flying-brick non-masked superhero.

I also remember that the time traveller goes back to visit himself at one time in the story and the version of him that had travelled back to see himself was nearly dead, and he had to figure out how to prevent himself from getting killed, however I don't recall the resolution to that problem, so perhaps he died at that point.

Comment: Story or comic?

Comment: This was a story, not a comic.

Comment: A novel or a short story?

Comment: Could this be *Worm*? I'm not sure if anyone there fits the bill, but there are several parahumans with time-altering abilities. One in particular called "Clockblocker" has quite the sense of humor, but his powers don't fit exactly.

Comment: Do you remember any other details about the plot? Other characters? Powers of other superheroes? Roughly when you read it, and if it was old or new?

Comment: @tobiasvl No, it wasn't worm. The name was something like "Wonderful Jim"

Comment: @broklynite: I wrote a bit more in the original post. I read it perhaps 10 years ago, and I think it was written in the form of multiple short stories. I think they were still being written.

Comment: Could it potentially be *Archvillain* by Barry Lyga with its antagonist hero, Mighty Mike, opposed by Kyle, who has similar powers but also super-intelligence? http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Archvillain

Comment: That is surprisingly similar to my story, however looking it over, it isn't the same one.

Comment: The *Dire* series has Timetripper, who's a hippy time traveler who is far from serious, and knows that he dies at some future time at the hand of the protagonist (who is nominally a supervillain), with one of the running threads being that he knows that the candles are lit at the time of his death, so they'll exchange dialogue about that when they meet to establish if this might be the last time. Doctor Dire only goes by that name, and has a speech tick where she cannot refer to herself with pronouns, but only by name.

Comment: From some cursory searching, have you looked at "Super Powereds" by Drew Hayes

Comment: @paul- it doesn't look like that is correct for this story